# How to manage Hahn Air bookings?

Tags: airlines, bookings, seating

Expedia sold me a Hahn Air flight operated by VietJet. They gave a ticket number and a confirmation code, as is done with other airlines. I would like to manage by booking and select seats, plus perhaps buy luggage allowance but I cannot find where to do it.

A Google search for Hahn Air gives pages that are intended for travel agents and charter airlines but I cannot find anything consumer accessible. In hope it might work, I tried both the ticket number and confirmation code on the VietJet website. Neither were recognized unfortunately.

**Where to we select seats and buy luggage allowance for Hahn Air flights?**

Comment: Have you been able to check your [travel details](https://www.hahnair.com/en/agents/travel-details) with this tool?

Comment: Yes, I can see the details but there are no actionable items there, other than send the displayed details via email.

Comment: Very annoying :-) Perhaps [contacting VietJet via FB might](https://www.facebook.com/pg/Vietjetglobal/about/?ref=page_internal) get an answer.

Comment: Hahn Air is a very strange "airline". Interested to see what becomes of this.

Comment: The Vietjet website expects an 8 digit confirmation code - if your Hahn confirmation has one of those then you can enter it here to check it's valid without having to figure out which order they have your names in: https://gds.vietjetair.com/?lang=en - the main manage my booking page is a bit of a pain when it comes to name order (it says Middle, Given - but expects them in passport order - so probably Given, Middle for Westerners).

Comment: No neither of my Hahn Air numbers. I also have another flights on Vietjet, with numbers that worked, so I had figured out the name order and, I agree, it is unusual.

Comment: It may simply be that Hahn Air does not have a website that allows passengers to select seats and buy luggage allowance. Not every airline in the world has such a site. You could try to contact them or VietJet by phone to at least get seats assigned in advance if they're set up to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no client-accessible interface to manage Hahn Air bookings. One has to write to them directly via email at service@hahnair.com. They will send confirmation and any additional details requested.

Any details or changes have to be undertaken over the phone with the operating carrier, this includes additional luggage. Since there is no confirmation number from the operating airline, it is not possible to check in online either.

Hahn Air says:

> Hahn Air as a validating carrier cannot offer further assistance regarding excess baggage/additional baggage, please liaise directly with the operating carrier.

And their confirmation include the following information:

> - Online check-in is not possible. Please check in for free at the respective check-in counters at the airport.
> - For all H1 flights, no baggage through-checkin is possible. It is recommended to arrive at the airport at least 2 hours prior to departure.
> - Please add passenger contact details  as SSRCTCM or CTCE for the operating airlines information.

Answer (score 5):

Hi Itai it would be great if you could drop us an email including your PNR and ticket number to service@hahnair.com. Our colleagues from Service Desk will have a look into you booking and assist you with your request. Kind regards, your Hahn Air Team

Comment: Just to make this transparent to us who are not in the business, could you please spell out the acronym PNR?  (Do you mean passport number?) Thanks.

Comment: You have been contacted, although I have no access to the PNR. I had heard the term before but found this to be a an interesting introduction: https://hasbrouck.org/articles/PNR.html - It really does not seem like it is something which is customer accessible.

Comment: Dear Itai, thanks for the response. Could you provide us with your HR ticket number for the records. Thank you very much. Best regards, your Hahn Air Team

Answer (score 0):

Hann Air says related to check in: for flights not showing H1, you should always try to check in online on the operating carrier’s webpage. Some webpages do not recognize the Hahn Air ticket number and it is only possible to check-in at the airport. If you don’t know the operating carrier for your flight, please contact your travel agency.

Related to luggage Hann Air says:
As a ticketing carrier Hahn Air is not entitled to offer assistance regarding baggage issues, these are determined by the operating carrier. Please contact your travel agency or the operating carrier directly.